Purpose of this RSNUB
This image is from the schematic of an overvoltage protection regulator.
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/eval-board-schematic/1018babcsch.pdf

I'm trying to find out the purpose of the RSNUB & CSNUB at the input of the circuit, having in mind there's a TVS diode connected in the same path.
Normally it's used to suppress any voltage transients but in this scenario it's not clear to me.

Your suspicion on handling transients is correct.
The SNUB in the reference designator for the resistor and capacitor likely indicates it's use for snubbing in the input.
A snubber is used for handling excessive transients, particularly excessive noise during boot. When you turn on a switching power supply, it can generate a considerable amount of noise. To prevent a false-positive shutdown from an overshoot from your input, you need to filter it out.

So if I understand, this RC snub behaves as a High Pass Filter??

@marcosbc Not quite. It is low pass, you're blocking higher frequencies. The naming can be confusing but thinking of it as "you're allowing low frequencies to pass".

Ok, I thought it was high pass based on this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516911/rc-low-pass-filter-capacitor-in-series-or-in-parallel

@marcosbc I can see the confusion. Notice that this RC network is going to ground, thus being in parallel to rest of the pin configuration. There's no connection to the rest of the output.
